# PHP page can connect to some databases on MySQL server, but not others?

Tags: php, mysql, database

hope you're doing well.

I'm trying to connect a .php web page to a MySQL database on localhost. When I downloaded my SQL server, the database contained all the databases shown in this picture **EXCEPT FOR 'favr'**

[image: Databases on server:]

When I try to connect to the database 'mysql' or 'phpmyadmin' it works like a charm and I can display table data. However, I created the database 'favr' and **I can't connect to that one.** Does anyone have an idea why this might be? My user ('root', with no password) has full privileges for 'favr' as well as all other databases.

Since you asked, here's the connection code:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
//define('DB_PASS', 'new_password');

$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, "");
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    echo "connected";
}
mysql_select_db('mysql', $conn) or die('Could not select database.');
$query = "SELECT * FROM db";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
if(!$result){
die("Query failed");
}
```

This works fine, and I can print the table "db" in database "MySQL." When I sub "favr" for "mysql" though, I get the 'could not select database' error on line 12.

Comment: have you run query inside `MySQL` which you are running from code? I  mean **are you sure you have tables in `favr` database?**

Comment: Can you show us your DB connection code?

Comment: Edited it to include the code.

Comment: I have flagged this question as **can no longer be reproduced** which the OP agrees with in a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems evident that this is some sort of user error that we cannot replicate from your question information.

You are saying that you **can** connect by using `mysql_connect("local_host","root","")`.
Which is independent of your database selection function/line:
`mysql_select_db('mysql')`

But when you try:  `mysql_select_db('favr')` after connecting, your code backtracks and says there was a problem with the connection.  This is hogwash.  PHP is not going to change its mind about an earlier true/false condition based on a subsequent function.

The reality is, you should take this opportunity to upgrade your mysql_ functions to mysqli_ functions.  Then you can start experimenting/debugging with:

```
if($db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","favr")){
    echo "Connected without password to 'favr'";
}else{
    echo "Connection error: ",mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

If there really is something foul happening, you'll be better able to express the occurrence and deliver a reproducible failure for us.

Comment: Sorry mick! I misspoke. I meant I was getting the error at line 12: "could not select database." I'm sill having the issue, so if this changes anything I would still greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @JacksonN Please implement my suggested mysqli_ functions.  Then test again and edit your question to show the upgraded functions and error messages.  Why would you NOT use passwords anyhow?

Comment: @JacksonN Please also post the results of `SELECT * 
FROM  \`information_schema\`.\`USER_PRIVILEGES\`` as well as `SHOW GRANTS`

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but I just uninstalled what I was using (XAMPP) and went for WAMP. Now I have a working connection with my database.

Comment: @JacksonN So how shall this question be resolved then?  I don't think my answer solved it.  It seems you don't have an answer to post.  Do you want to delete this question as it could not be replicated (sparing moderators from handling a flag of "could not be replicated")?  All questions on SO deserve some sort of resolution.  What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like the way to go. I'll delete it.